# TFS - shared step creation

Tags: tfs

Is there a limit to the number of steps that can be included when creating a shared step in TFS?  I have a process that is repeated for many test cases.  The process contains 12 steps so I wanted to create a shared step rather than write out all 12 steps each time.  However, when I highlight those steps and click Create Shared Step, I do not get the box to input the title of the shared step.  This leads me to believe there may be a limit to the number of steps that can be included in a shared step.

Comment: I Just tried do this. Able to give title but after that it is giving error that "Filed Application cannot be blank" . But the test case from where i am creating the shared step has the application already selected (Application Name - MAiS(1240) )

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it depends on where you're creating the test case, and what version you're using.

Microsoft Test Manager 2013 doesn't have a limit - I just created a shared step with 13 steps.

Your version of the TFS web portal may not support this: TFS 2012 web portal doesn't support creating shared steps at all.

VSTS has a limit of 10 steps to create shared steps from existing steps. The workaround would be to either group your steps into two shared steps, or to see if you can add steps to the shared steps after you create them.